# Kotlin grouping, mapping and so on

Tags: kotlin, collections, group-by, mapping

I know that a lot of this topics exists but I don't understand this topic at all. And an exact explanation of what is happening for a beginner is needed.

I have a list of persons:

```
    val person1 = Person("A", 8, 24,"darts")
    val person2 = Person("A", 8, 24,"football")
    val person3 = Person("A", 2, 24,"basketball")
    val person4 = Person("B", 8, 24,"skiing")
    val person5 = Person("B", 1, 24,"snowboard")
```

where

```
data class Person (val street: String, val number: Int, val age: Int, val hobby: String){
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$street $number $age $hobby"
    }
}
```

And now to sum up. If I use a groupBy the result will be Map with key, and values Am I right?
Where keys are the atrributes on which I am grouping by like:

`var grouping = list.groupBy { it.street }`

result is:

`{A=[A 8 24 darts, A 8 24 football, A 2 24 basketball], B=[B 8 24 skiing, B 1 24 snowboard]}`

And now I would like to group by multiple fields like street and number. How to do this?
And moreover I would like to specify a LIST (I have to do some kind of projection from this map?) of hobbies which people have under adresses and numbers. For example under adress A number 8 i have a list of (darts,football).

@Edit
Do I have somehow to divide this list as 2nd object class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `groupBy` returns a map where the keys are whatever was returned by the lambda and values are lists of items from the original list.

To group by a pair of things, you need to be able to have a key that represents all those things and be unique. The probably means another data class, or maybe you could concatenate the as a String.

```
data class Address(val street: String, val number: Int)

val grouping = list.groupBy { Address(it.street, it.number) }
```

And to make the values of the map simply the hobby, you can use `mapkeys`:

```
val addressesToHobbies = grouping.mapKeys { it.map(Person::hobby) }
```

Comment: Thank you. But it creates a list inside list of objects. How to receive only a 1 list of these hobbies?

Comment: If it's a small set of data, I'd skip all of the above and simply filter the original list: `val hobbiesAtAddressA8 = list.filter { it.street == "A" && it.number = 8 }`. If these are large sets of data that you will access repeatedly, you can make the above grouping and pull the list you need like this: `val hobbiesAtAddressA8 = addressesToHobbies[Address("A", 8)]`.